# soundManager loaded from ajax plays previously selected song

Tags: jquery, ajax, soundmanager2

I have a page where different music albums are showed, and I'm initalizing a soundManager in it.
When an album is clicked, a view is loaded in ajax with some mp3 links in it.
This works fine and the music plays. (I've based my script on: http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/mp3-player-button/basic.html )

When another album is clicked, I'm calling

```
soundManager.stopAll();
```

to stop any currently playing track. This stops the track currently playing, but when I click on a track in a newly opened "album view", the previously selected track, plays on top of the newly clicked one.

I've tried using soundManager.unload(); and soundManager.destruct(); without success...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
var basicMP3Player = null;

soundManager.onready(function() {
  // soundManager.createSound() etc. may now be called
  basicMP3Player = new BasicMP3Player();
});
```

I used:

```
if ( typeof basicMP3Player !== "undefined" && basicMP3Player) {
    basicMP3Player.destruct();
} 
else {
    var basicMP3Player = null;
}

soundManager.onready(function() {
  // soundManager.createSound() etc. may now be called
  basicMP3Player = new BasicMP3Player();
});
```

The problem is that now when I load another "album view", the config isn't loaded properly and the "playNext" or "autoPlay" attributes aren't working...

Comment: Were you ever able to sort this out?

Comment: apparently the .destruct() method is not available anymore... and here am I, stuck again :(

Answer (score 1):

Well... this is old, but I had this issue and found the answer
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22208257/execute-soundmanager2-after-ajax-response)

Seems you just need to call:

```js
soundManager.reboot();
```

After your ajax call success.